# how to compare the query value from url to id using react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to check if the url contains ?query_param if so then get its value and compare that value to an id.

consider the url /path/20?query_parm=2234

and i have to get the param_id and compare it with the item id.

so i do something like below,

```
handle_location = (path) => {
    let opened_item, param_id;
       param_id = new 
           URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search).get('query_param');
       if (this.state.items) {
            opened_item = this.state.items.find(item => item.id === 
            param_id);
        }
};
```

the data structure for items is below,

```
items = [{
              id: 2244;
              attributes: something;
          }
          {  
              id: 33;
              attributes: nothing;
          }]
```

But this gives the opened_item value undefined since item.id is never equal to param_id... because of type being different.

How can i fix this...or is there a better way to find the query_param from url and get its value and use it accordingly to find the item that matches with the query_param value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you understand that both data types are different, you could use avoid using strict equality and leverage type coercion which would work

```
item.id == param_id
```

The most efficient way though would be to convert `param_id` to the appropriate type before comparing e.g.

```
param_id = parseInt(param_id, 10);
```

It means one conversion and you can keep the strict equality

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either cast both of the values to the same type(either Number or String) and then perform the comparison or you could use `==` operator which will try to coerce the types automatically(not recommended). You can also always fall back to some default value if none of the items matched the id.

```
if (this.state.items) {
    opened_item = this.state.items.find(item => item.id === 
    param_id) || 'some default value'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
const param_id = this.props.match.params.id